# How to combined table 2 value in table 1 whare id field is same?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Table 1

```
id   |  name  | coupn |
-------+--------+------
 PR001 | DC001  |    5
 PR002 | DC001  |    5
 PR003 | DC001  |    6
 PR004 | DC002  |    7
 PR005 | DC003  |    3
 PR006 | DC003  |    11
 PR007 | DC004  |    10
 PR008 | DC005  |    66
```

Table 2

```
id   |  name  | bonus|
-------+--------+------
 PR001 | res |    10
 PR002 | des|    2
 PR003 | DC  |    1
 PR004 | Drf  |    7
 PR005 | wed|    3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? please post what you tries so far and what's your expecting results?

Comment: You may want to describe how you want to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Oh foxpro  my first programing language

Visual Foxpro 5+ can run most of the SQL92 commands with modifications to its syntax

standard sql commands will work for a join

```
Select * from table1 left join table2 on table2.id = table1.id 
into cursor my_joined_tabled
```

this will create a read only cursor  aka in memory only table.  Cursor in foxpro are in memory tables

for a union

```
select cast(columns to same data type), and number of columns from table1
union 
select cast(columns to same data type), and number of columns from table2
into cursor my_unioned_table
```

if you want to use Xbase commands  that's allot more code and those brains cells fell dormant 10 years ago